# can't pass / unlock Secure startup with PIN code

Tags: security, boot, lg

I have a problem with my LG G5 (but saw it happens in other LG phones)
I have a PIN screen lock and I changed it a couple of days ago.
I was talking on the phone when it restarted (I remember the battery was hot).
Now the phone is on "Secure startup" and I had 30 tries to unlock it (15 remained).
I have the "white" [screen](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=71690001&postcount=27) (and can't get to the "black" screen, more details down).

I saw a number of [posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/lgg5/comments/7a58it/startup_password_required/) on this issue.
I can only enter PIN (no character keyboard).
I tried the current and previous PIN. Also tried: 0, 0000, 00000, PUK code.
Some of those tried also on safe mode.
When tried to fill the screen with zeros as much as possible and tried to unlock, I got a screen that said something like (translated):
In order to open the lock, turn off the phone and power it on again.
Did it but didn't change. Than I thought I should have pressed restart (instead of turning off and then on) but didn't got to this screen, just stayed on the same screen with one try less.

I can get to factory reset, only this [option](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rQNENaJYZg) yes/no.
I don't want to hard reset because some files are not backed up.
Also can get to Fastboot mode and Download mode.

If I restart (or power off and on) the phone is on flight mode.
I can call to emergency numbers, and when I call and hangs up, suddenly there is a cellular connection and 4G data.
In this situation I can receive calls, but still can call only emergency numbers.

The phone is not rooted and I don't use special ROM or something like that.
From time to time it makes tick sounds (like pressing a button) every few seconds. The rest of the time it doesn't make any sound.
The computer recognizes the phone and installs the driver - "Android bootloader interface" but I can't see the phone on my computer.
Also tried to connect through Google Find but it can't locate the phone and the lock option there doesn't seem to do anything (writes request sent).

I also have a memory card, do you know if the data on it is OK? (I don't have a card reader)

There is a problem contacting stores because of the Corona.

Appreciate any help,
Thanks very much!